# Python Twisted with callInThread

Tags: python, twisted

I stripped down my app but this should give you an example of what i'm doing

```
def run_app(f):
    p = Popen(['/usr/bin/app'],stdout=PIPE)
    while True:
        o = p.stdout.readline()
        if o == '' and p.poll() != None: break

        reactor.callFromThread(f, o)

class Echo(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):

        reactor.callInThread(run_app, self.appDataReceived)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        data = data.strip()
        if data == "getmore":
            print "getmore"

    def appDataReceived(self, u):
        print u

def main():
    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = Echo
    reactor.listenTCP(3646, factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have an app which I want to connect in and run a app that continually spits out data to stdout. Right now my app works but the issue is when the client exits the socket connection the /usr/bin/app still continues to run. The more socket connections made the more this app is still running.

Is there anyway from the Echo Procool to kill the run_app() function?

Comment: Can you check if the condition is ever met: if o == '' and p.poll() != None: break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few suggestions that I can make and hopefully it will resolve your issues.

Don't use reactor.callFromThread, instead use deferToThread

```
from twisted.internet.threads import deferToThread
deferredObj = threads.deferToThread(run_app, self.appDataReceived)
```

Just like you start the thread when the connection is made. You need to act when connection is lost.

Example code:

```
class Echo(Protocol):
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print reason
        # which is crude, there should be a more elegant answer
        reactor.stop()
```

Agreed that deferToThread is optimized for short-running tasks. In fact, it is better to re do your code so that you could call the thread to just run the process and return the result.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use threads and Popen.  Use [Twisted's process support](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html).  Also, your `Echo` protocol [needs framing](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/ws/2003/11/25/protocols.html) or there's no guarantee that it will ever receive the `"getmore"` string.